# Kotlin-Android: Crear un PopupMenu y llenarlo mientras se escribe en un EditText sin perder el foco

Tags: android, kotlin, edittext, focus

Estoy intentando crear un PopupMenu que se llene dinamicamente mientras se escribe en un EditText, los datos los extraigo de una base de datos local, con eso no tengo problema, el detalle esta en que cada que escribo una letra en el EditText, se actualiza la lista pero ya no puedo seguir escribiendo de corrido en el EditText porque este pierde el foco y tengo que seleccionar nuevamente el EditText para escribir solo una letra mas.

```
etProduct.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (count > 1){
                    val coincidentList = buyQueryDB.searchProduct(text.toString())
                    val coincidentMenu = PopupMenu(applicationContext,etProduct)
                    coincidentMenu.menu.add("+ "+getText(R.string.new_product))

                    // Llenado de todo el Popup

                    coincidentMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {item: MenuItem? ->
                        println(item)
                        true
                    }
                    coincidentMenu.show()
                    etProduct.requestFocus()
                }
            }
        })
```

intente agregar esta linea después de que se muestre el PopuMenu para intentar regresar el foco al EditText pero no resulto:

```
etProduct.requestFocus()
```

No se si el Popup que estoy implementando no es el correcto o como configurarlo para que no tome el foco cada que se muestra.

Estoy intentando algo como esto:
[image: Popup mientras se escribe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
etProduct.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (count > 1){
                    val coincidentList = buyQueryDB.searchProduct(text.toString())
                    val coincidentMenu = PopupMenu(applicationContext,etProduct)
                    coincidentMenu.menu.add("+ "+getText(R.string.new_product))

                    // Llenado de todo el Popup

                    coincidentMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {item: MenuItem? ->
                        println(item)
                        true
                    }
                    coincidentMenu.show()
                    etProduct.clearFocus()
                    etProduct.requestFocus()
                }
            }
        })
```

Pero tu app  no va a funcionar del todo bien debido al cambio en el focus entre el teclado y el editText.

Para lograr el comportamiento que buscas te recomiento usar autocompletetextview, una ventaja de hacerlo así es que puedes cargar todos los valores de tu base de datos y el widget los irá filtrando conforme el usuario escriba.

```
class KotlinActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kotlin)
        
        val list=ArrayList<String>()//Aqui va tu lista obtenida de la BD
        list.add("Hola")
        list.add("Hola2")
        list.add("Hola3")
        list.add("Adios")
        list.add("Kotlin")
        val customAdapter=CustomAdapter(this@KotlinActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
        customAdapter.onItemClickListener=object:CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onItemClick(value:String?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@KotlinActivity,"Item: $value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        etProduct.setAdapter(customAdapter)

    }
}
```

Para capturar el evento onClick necesitas agregar un custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int,list:List<String>):ArrayAdapter<String>(context,resource,list) {

    var onItemClickListener:OnItemClickListener?=null

    override fun getCount():Int{
            return super.getCount()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): String? {
        return super.getItem(position)
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        //Si quieres usar un custom view puedes descomentar lo siguiente(reemplazando los ids por tus propios ids)
        /*val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parent)
        view.textView.text=getItem(position)
        view.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClickListener?.onItemClick(getItem(position))
            }
        return view
            */

        return TextView(context).also{
            it.text=getItem(position)
            it.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClickListener?.onItemClick(getItem(position))
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick( value:String?)
    }
```

XML de tu activity

Edita tu etproduct para que sea un AutoCompleteTextView en lugar de un EditText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".KotlinActivity"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/etProduct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Intente tu solución con el autocompletetextview usando tu ejemplo, primero me tope con un error en `etProduct.setAdapter(customAdapter)` investigando encontré que hace falta: `val etProduct = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.etProduct)` y eso me llevo a otro error donde tuve que agregar `@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")` al inicio del metodo, con eso compilo pero al ingresar al activity se detuvo y me arrojo este error: `widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: La vía por autocompletetextview suena buena idea, solo tengo que entender bien como funciona esto, soy nuevo en android y esto me da dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Lo siento, olvidé indicarte que tambien hicieras el cambio en el xml de tu layout, ya edité la respuesta, no deberías tener problemas

Comment: Excelente eso soluciono todos mis errores, ya solo me falta darle formato a la lista de sugerencias supongo que será con algún layout personalizado pero ya de eso me encargo, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Me alegra que te sirviera, dejé un bloque de código comentado en el CustomAdapter.getView() por si querías personalizar los items con un custom layout